# Uploading file to imgur.com with REST API problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, imgur

I am trying to upload image to imgur.com(apidocs.imgur.com). But for some reasons the request is successfull and provides me the image link but the image does not shows up in imgur.com

```
def upload_imgur(image_name):
    imgur_upload_url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image"
    # payload = {'image': 'R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP'}
    files = {}
    payload = {'image': open(image_name, 'rb')}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Client-ID {} Bearer {}'.format(client_id, access_token)
    }
    response = requests.request('POST',imgur_upload_url, headers=headers, files=payload)
    logger.info(headers)
    try:
        link = response.json()
        logger.info('Data link {}'.format(link))
        return True
    except KeyError:
        link = "Failed"
        return False
```

Response:

```
{'data': {'id': 'b1hOr9v', 'title': None, 'description': None, 'datetime': 1555000696, 'type': 'image/jpeg', 'animated': False, 'width': 225, 'height': 225, 'size': 2844, 'views': 0, 'bandwidth': 0, 'vote': None, 'favorite': False, 'nsfw': None, 'section': None, 'account_url': None, 'account_id': 0, 'is_ad': False, 'in_most_viral': False, 'has_sound': False, 'tags': [], 'ad_type': 0, 'ad_url': '', 'edited': '0', 'in_gallery': False, 'deletehash': 'ulCxGeNZk8r34s3', 'name': '', 'link': 'https://i.imgur.com/b1hOr9v.jpg'}, 'success': True, 'status': 200}
```

But there is not image in my account. Please help!!

Comment: Not sure if that's the only problem, but your Authorization header is wrong. It should be just `Bearer <access_token>`, without the `Client-ID`.

Comment: Also, you should use a `with` context manager to properly close that file that you're uploading.